# public and secret keys <name> don't correspond

Tags: tezos-client, key, private

I generated a new address on a node and then overwrote it. 
I have the public key hash (starts with 'edpk') and the password. I also have the private key hash (starts with 'encrypted:edesk1')
I imported the public key:

```
$tezos-client show address <name> -S

Hash: tz1...
Public Key: edpk...
```

When I run:

```
$tezos-client import secret key <name> encrypted:edesk1...
```

the response is :

```
Enter password for encrypted key: 
Error:
  public and secret keys '<name>' don't correspond, please don't use --force
```

In the above examples. I replaced the actual name I gave the wallet with '< name>', however when I run the command I am replacing < name> with the actual alias.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Reset everything. Run `tezos-client forget address <alias> --force` I hope you understand that `<name>` is not a literal string and that you should be replacing that with real values: Example: `tezos-client forget address mykey1 --force`

Then, ONLY import the encrypted secret key as you did above. The client will automatically extract the public key hash, and the public key for you.